# RequireJS see source module when error occurs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

We're doing some much-needed refactoring, and as a result, a lot of errors.

In RequireJS, when a module is not found, or it gets a 404 error, it says:

```
GET http://localhost/resources/wrong/path/main.js 404 (Not Found) require.js:1895
Uncaught Error: Script error for: main
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

How can I see which model is doing the require call for `main` aside from painstakingly searching through the entire codebase?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind doing a little hack with the requirejs source code (provided you are not using the minified version). You can replace line 1696 with the following lines

```
   var rel = registry ? registry[data.id] : undefined;
   var pmap = rel ? (rel.map ? rel.map.parentMap : undefined) : undefined;
   var purl = pmap ? pmap.url : "?";
   var errorMsg = 'Script error while loading '+ data.id + ' from ' + purl;
   return onError(makeError('scripterror', errorMsg, evt, [data.id]));
```

I am not recommending the above as a solution, but it has been useful to me, and might be useful for someone else too.